# Create offline map for android

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography, mapnik

I am using mapsforge but I have problem with street names.I would like to develop an offline vector map for a city like osmAnd offline map or an offline vector map in mapnik format.Could you please guide me what should I do?

Comment: Please explain us your problem with street names in detail. Otherwise there is no way we can help you.

Comment: I want too see highway names in zoom level 14 but mapsforge not show the names,something like mapnik form

Comment: Just for the reference, the question for the original issue is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152483/highway-captions-not-shown).

Comment: Hello mozhi, you should be aware that you can edit the map rendering style definition in each instance of mapsforge. See the documentation in mapsforge wiki on github.com, especially at https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Rendertheme.md ... ask on mapsforge mailinglist when you get stuck in detail.

Comment: Hello I have used rendertheme but I didn't get good result.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may try to get parts you need from OSMAnd (it's opensource) https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand
- You may use https://getyourmap.com/ (there are free usage plan)

Comment: Thanks for your response.but I want to make an application via eclipse I need to make offline map of a city in my app somthing like osmAnd offline map or mapnik form

Comment: And both of these options are offline vector renders with Android support, which allows you to save data for your city and use a map pane in your app. offline.

Comment: The first one is a little bit complex to find out where should I start,is there any guidance to guide me step by step?  For second one It has explained to use in Android Studio not in Eclipse !! What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Yep, first one is complex. Creating Android app. in Eclipse is similar to Android Studio. Add libs directory, add it in gradle file, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I haven't used gradle yet,you mean I should study it and use it in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, or add new library for Eclipse in any other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good guidance.I could run GLMap from http://getyourmap.com,but I have some questions I'll be appreciate you if you could help me in this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/153311/54417