# How can I customize GLMap offline vector map?

Tags: openstreetmap, offline, glmap

I am using GLMap from https://getyourmap.com/ and I have two questions:

1. In my vector map the street name is shown in two languages I want to show in one language. How can I change that?
2. Where can I give information about adding marker or set locations?

Answer (score 2):

1. Names and labeling rules are in default style. They are follows http://www.mapcss.org/ specification with some extras.

Open `DefaultStyle.bundle/Style.mapcss` most of the names marked as

```
{ 
  ...
  text:eval(locTag('name')); 
  ...
}
```

You could use

```
text:eval(any(tag('name:en'), tag('name')));
```

In that case, `name:en` will be used for names first, and if there is no `name:en`, `name` will take it's place.

2. Markers could be added via GLImage or GeoJSON with custom style but I've also have some difficulties here, and can't support you with working example.

So the best way is to ask getyourmap dev. team.

Comment: when I change Style.mapcss the app crashes

Comment: sorry I couldn't find where can I communicate with getyourmap dev team ?!

Comment: @mozhijafr There is an email address of evgen@getyourmap.com at the bottom of https://getyourmap.com/ - that may be the best place to start.